# cleveref: \lcnamecref fails to work with theorem names that are not pre-defined

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, capitalization, cleveref

I'm using `cleveref` with the `capitalise` option, and I'd like to use the `\lcnamecref` command to give the name of one of my theorems in the text. But if this is not one of the theorem types pre-defined in `cleveref` (Lemma, Theorem etc.) then I get an error message.  Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\crefname{mythm}{Mytheorem}{Mytheorems}
\newtheorem{mythm}{Mytheorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{mythm}\label{m}
foo
\end{mythm}
That was a \lcnamecref{m}.
\end{document}
```

When I compile I get the error message

```
! Argument of \MakeUppercase has an extra }.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I get no error if I use `\Crefname` instead of `\crefname`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\lcnamecref` will force lowercase for the names defined with `\Crefname` (the upper-case variant), so you have to use this macro in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

% \crefname{mythm}{Mytheorem}{Mytheorems}
\Crefname{mythm}{Mytheorem}{Mytheorems}
\newtheorem{mythm}{Mytheorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{mythm}\label{m}
foo
\end{mythm}
That was a \lcnamecref{m}.
\end{document}
```

[image]